# pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h not found when colcon build, but appriopriate packages are installed

Tags: ros, ros2, c++

I bought a LiDAR D4 on AliExpress and received a package from the buyer with a driver for ROS2. Unfortunately, I get the following errors when calling `colcon build`:

```
colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> cspc_lidar
--- stderr: cspc_lidar                             
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp: In member function ‘void Point_cloud_optimize::PointCloudFilter(LaserScan*)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:25:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   25 |         for (i0 = 0; i0 < Scan->points.size(); i0++)
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:28:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   28 |                 i1 = i1 < Scan->points.size() ? i1 : i1 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:30:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   30 |                 i2 = i2 < Scan->points.size() ? i2 : i2 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:32:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   32 |                 i3 = i3 < Scan->points.size() ? i3 : i3 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:155:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  155 |         for (i0 = 0; i0 < Scan->points.size(); i0++)
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:158:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  158 |                 i1 = i1 < Scan->points.size() ? i1 : i1 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:160:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  160 |                 i2 = i2 < Scan->points.size() ? i2 : i2 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:162:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  162 |                 i3 = i3 < Scan->points.size() ? i3 : i3 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:164:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  164 |                 i4 = i4 < Scan->points.size() ? i4 : i4 - Scan->points.size();
      |                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp: In member function ‘int Point_cloud_optimize::UltrasonicSimRanging(LaserPoint&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:228:13: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  228 |         int i, index;
      |             ^
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:229:15: warning: unused variable ‘tempdep’ [-Wunused-variable]
  229 |         short tempdep;
      |               ^~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:253:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
  253 | }
      | ^
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp: In member function ‘void Point_cloud_optimize::lidar_blocked_judge(int)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:341:60: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
  341 |                 printf("lidar 雷达被严重遮挡百分之七十 %d,%d\n",node_lidar.lidar_block.lidar_zero_count,node_lidar.scan_node_count);
      |                                                           ~^                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            |                                                       |
      |                                                            int                                                     size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                                                           %ld
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp: In member function ‘void Point_cloud_optimize::lidar_blocked_init()’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:404:69: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
  404 |                         if((angle >= 0 && angle < 90)|| angle > 270 && angle <=360){
      |                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp:375:21: warning: unused variable ‘temp’ [-Wunused-variable]
  375 |         float r, d, temp;
      |                     ^~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp: In function ‘void flushSerial()’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:53:24: warning: unused variable ‘bytes_read’ [-Wunused-variable]
   53 |                 size_t bytes_read = node_lidar.serial_port->read_data(buffer, len);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp: In function ‘bool lidar_state_judgment()’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:86:45: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
   86 |                 printf("状态异常重新启动 %lld\n",lidar_status_time);
      |                                          ~~~^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             |    |
      |                                             |    uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                                             long long int
      |                                          %ld
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:62:21: warning: unused variable ‘status_judge’ [-Wunused-variable]
   62 |         static bool status_judge = false;     //整体状态判断
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:65:21: warning: variable ‘lidar_start_flag’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   65 |         static bool lidar_start_flag = false; //下发雷达启动指令后的雷达反馈标志
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp: In function ‘int read_forever()’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:200:82: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
  200 |                                                         printf("full----- count=%d,time=%lld\n",scan_count,current_times());
      |                                                                                 ~^              ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                  |              |
      |                                                                                  int            size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                                                                                 %ld
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:200:92: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int64_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
  200 |                                                         printf("full----- count=%d,time=%lld\n",scan_count,current_times());
      |                                                                                         ~~~^               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                            |                            |
      |                                                                                            long long int                int64_t {aka long int}
      |                                                                                         %ld
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp: In member function ‘result_t Lidar_Data_Processing::waitSpeedRight(uint8_t, uint64_t)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:94:56: warning: unused parameter ‘cmd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   94 | result_t Lidar_Data_Processing::waitSpeedRight(uint8_t cmd,uint64_t timeout)
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~^~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp: In member function ‘result_t Lidar_Data_Processing::waitResponseHeader(uint8_t, uint64_t)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:366:28: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
  366 |       printf("data**%d,%d,%d\n",check_sum_cal,recvBuffer[remainSize-1],remainSize);
      |                           ~^                                           ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            |                                           |
      |                            int                                         size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                           %ld
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp: In member function ‘result_t Lidar_Data_Processing::waitPackage_coin(node_info*, uint32_t)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:858:9: warning: unused variable ‘k’ [-Wunused-variable]
  858 |     int k;
      |         ^
In file included from /home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp:12:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.h: In constructor ‘Serial_Port::Serial_Port(const string&, uint32_t, Timeout, bytesize_t, parity_t, stopbits_t, flowcontrol_t)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.h:102:14: warning: ‘Serial_Port::bytesize_’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
  102 |   bytesize_t bytesize_;       // Size of the bytes
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.h:101:12: warning:   ‘parity_t Serial_Port::parity_’ [-Wreorder]
  101 |   parity_t parity_;           // Parity
      |            ^~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp:31:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
   31 | Serial_Port::Serial_Port(const string &port, uint32_t baudrate, Timeout timeout,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:758:11: warning: variable ‘AngleCorrectForDistance’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  758 |   int32_t AngleCorrectForDistance = 0;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:760:11: warning: unused variable ‘package_type’ [-Wunused-variable]
  760 |   uint8_t package_type = 0;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:762:12: warning: unused variable ‘start’ [-Wunused-variable]
  762 |   uint16_t start;
      |            ^~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp:763:12: warning: unused variable ‘stop’ [-Wunused-variable]
  763 |   uint16_t stop;
      |            ^~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp: In member function ‘bool Serial_Port::setBaudrate(long unsigned int)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp:578:11: warning: unused variable ‘new_baud’ [-Wunused-variable]
  578 |   speed_t new_baud = static_cast<speed_t>(baudrate);
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp: In member function ‘bool Serial_Port::setCustomBaudRate(long unsigned int)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/serial_port.cpp:571:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  571 | }
      | ^
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp: At global scope:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/node_lidar.cpp:62:21: warning: ‘status_judge’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   62 |         static bool status_judge = false;     //整体状态判断
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘void pcloud_build_by_scan(LaserScan&, pcloud_t&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:44:21: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<LaserPoint>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   44 |   for (int i = 0; i < outscan.points.size(); i++)
      |                   ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:46:11: warning: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘point_t’ {aka ‘struct _point_’}; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
   46 |     memset(&point, 0, sizeof(point_t));
      |     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:8:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.h:52:16: note: ‘point_t’ {aka ‘struct _point_’} declared here
   52 | typedef struct _point_
      |                ^~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘int find_index(point_t, pcloud_t&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:105:9: warning: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘point_t’ {aka ‘struct _point_’}; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
  105 |   memset(&point_min, 0, sizeof(point_t));
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:8:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.h:52:16: note: ‘point_t’ {aka ‘struct _point_’} declared here
   52 | typedef struct _point_
      |                ^~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:124:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  124 |   if (point_min.index > pcloud.data.size())
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘bool intersect(LineSegment, LineSegment, Vector2D&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:167:10: warning: unused variable ‘cross1’ [-Wunused-variable]
  167 |   double cross1 = position1.x * direction1.y - position1.y * direction1.x;
      |          ^~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘double pointToLineDist(point_t, double, double)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:439:10: warning: unused variable ‘y0’ [-Wunused-variable]
  439 |   double y0 = k * x0 + b;
      |          ^~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘bool line_judgment(std::vector<_point_>, point_t)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:462:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  462 |   if (line.size() <= reference)
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:467:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  467 |   if (line.size() <= reference)
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:471:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  471 |     for (int i = 1; i < line.size() - 1; i++)
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘void fitting_line(pcloud_t&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:542:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  542 |         if (line.size() >= calibration_params.line_judgment_point_num)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:560:63: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  560 |         if(point.index == point_last_one.index && line.size() >= calibration_params.line_judgment_point_num)
      |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:571:26: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  571 |   if(point_record2.index < pcloud.data.size()
      |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:572:28: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  572 |   &&  point_last_one.index < pcloud.data.size()
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:573:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  573 |   &&  point_record1.index < pcloud.data.size())
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:597:28: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  597 |     if (line_append.size() >= calibration_params.line_judgment_point_num)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:606:29: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  606 |             if (line.size() >= calibration_params.line_judgment_point_num)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:617:68: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::vector<_point_>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  617 |           if(point.index == point_append_last.index && line.size() >= calibration_params.line_judgment_point_num)
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:632:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<_point_> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  632 |     for (int i = 0; i < lines.size() - 1; i++)
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp: In function ‘void lidar_calibration(LaserScan&)’:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:662:11: warning: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of type ‘struct LaserPoint’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
  662 |     memset(&outscan_point, 0, sizeof(LaserPoint));
      |     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.h:4,
                 from /home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/calibration.cpp:8:
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/sdk/lidar_information.h:210:8: note: ‘struct LaserPoint’ declared here
  210 | struct LaserPoint
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/przemek/ldlidar_ros_ws/src/cspc_lidar_sdk_ros2_D4_1110/src/node_lidar_ros.cpp:11:10: fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
   11 | #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cspc_lidar.dir/build.make:174: CMakeFiles/cspc_lidar.dir/src/node_lidar_ros.cpp.o] Błąd 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/cspc_lidar.dir/all] Błąd 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Błąd 2
---
Failed   <<< cspc_lidar [5.17s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [5.45s]
  1 package failed: cspc_lidar
  1 package had stderr output: cspc_lidar
```

As far as I can see the biggest one is missing `pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h`. In my case, the `ros-humble-pcl-conversions` and `libpcl-dev` are installed and up to date.
I also tried adding the following line to `CMakeLists.txt`:
`set(PCL_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake")`

leading directly to PCL Conversions, but it didn't change anything.
This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(cspc_lidar)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

set(PCL_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake")

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(visualization_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL 1.12 REQUIRED)
#find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/cspc_lidar
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sdk
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


add_executable(cspc_lidar sdk/mtime.cpp sdk/node_lidar.cpp sdk/serial_port.cpp sdk/timer.cpp sdk/lidar_data_processing.cpp sdk/point_cloud_optimize.cpp sdk/calibration.cpp src/node_lidar_ros.cpp)

ament_target_dependencies(cspc_lidar
  "rclcpp"
  "sensor_msgs"
  "visualization_msgs"
  "geometry_msgs"
)

install(TARGETS
  cspc_lidar
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(DIRECTORY launch params
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

I don't know what to do anymore, I would appreciate your help